# Is the Geometric Series defined at x=0?

Tags: geometric-series

The geometric series is usually defined as $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a \cdot x^{k}$ where $x$ is on the interval $]-1;1[$, which includes $0$.

My Problem is that substituting $x=0$ for the first Term of the sum gives $a \cdot 0^{0} $. This is an indeterminate form and therefor undefined which means that $x=0$ should not be part of the domain.

I know that the both-sided $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} ( a\cdot x^{0} )$, as well as $\frac{a}{1-x}$ at $x=0$, are equal to $a$. Both shouldn't be reason enough for including $x=0$ in the domain. Under most circumstances having the Geometric Series at $x=0$ equate to $a$ is a good thing, but there must be a better reason for doing so.

Comment: When discussing power series like this, it is assumed (often explicitly) that $0^0 = 1$. While this isn't the convention everywhere in mathematics, it is very much the convention in these circumstances.

Comment: “Really”, the geometric series is $a+a\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^k$. The constant value is always there and needed/assumed. We write this as $x^0$ for convenience of putting it as one series, and because $x^0=1$ is a very good convention. So there is no need to worry about any limits, since plugging in $0$ in my first equation gives me just $a+a\cdot0=a$

Comment: For what it's worth, I view this as an issue associated with a specific way of representing a geometric series (and which can be fixed by defining $0^0=1),$ not something intrinsic about the geometric series itself.

Comment: @TheoBendit I have never seen any convention other then $0^0=1$ anywhere outside discussions on m.se about whether $0^0=1$.  It is so obviously sensible whether dealing with power series or binomial expansions or empty products or anywhere else you might want to use it.  It may make the function $0^x$ discontinuous at $x=0$ but that is unlikely to be an issue given that it is not defined for $x<0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally when dealing with power series (and indeed we do the same when dealing with polynomials), we define $0^0=1$. This is for various reasons, including that we want continuity. Furthermore, we wish for our summation notation to formalize the following notion:

$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots.$$

In particular, we only get this if we define $0^0=1$, as we wish to have

$$a_0x^0=a_0$$

for the first term, for **all** $x$, including $0$.

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for a comment.*

Consider $y=x^x$ and make $x=10^{-k}$ and ... compute

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \left(10^{-k}\right)^{10^{-k}} \\
 0 & 1.0000000000 \\
 1 & 0.7943282347 \\
 2 & 0.9549925860 \\
 3 & 0.9931160484 \\
 4 & 0.9990793900 \\
 5 & 0.9998848774 \\
 6 & 0.9999861846 \\
 7 & 0.9999983882 \\
 8 & 0.9999998158 \\
 9 & 0.9999999793 \\
 10 & 0.9999999977
\end{array}
\right)$$